# Grafana: daily statistic with prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, grafana

In grafana I would like to display the daily production of my PV system.

I have created the following query:

```
delta(growatt_epvtotal{device=~"$device"}[1d])
```

My problem is: if I see the production of yesterday it is not a same as my manufacturer application says.

Why?

Because if I select last 30 days the range finished in today at 12:12 for instance. If I create a 1d range (from yesterday 12:12 to today 12:12) it will count two half day (yesterday afternoon and today morning production)

How can query a last 30 day production for each day in grafana from prometheus?

I would like to display each bar with 00:00-23:59 range and show the last 30 day

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't use `delta` for counters: use increase instead. Also I'm not sure if you have power over this, but `growatt_epvtotal` should be `growatt_epv_total` to adhere to counter naming rules.

Comment: And regarding your problem: if you'll set min step in query options of your panel to 1d, you'll get changes by midnights. But be aware of some possible issues regarding timezones: Prometheus works in UTC, and midnight is taken by UTC also.

Comment: `increase(growatt_epvtotal{device=~"$device"}[1d] offset -1d)` seems to be working, I will do more tests to double check it.